# undefind method price in rails application with paypal integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, cart

I was working with paypal integration with rails3.I was following railscast agile web development 4th edition.
but my bad luck i can not make it working.

In my carts/show.html.haml file i have the following

```
   %table
    %tr
      %th Product
      %th Qty
      %th Unit Price
      %th Full Price

    - for cart in @cart.line_items
      %tr
        %td= cart.product.title
        %td= cart.quantity
        %td= cart.price
        %td= cart.full_price
    = link_to "Continue Shopping", products_url 
    = link_to "Checkout", @cart.paypal_url(products_url)
```

then in my app/model/cart.rb model i have the paypal method

```
   has_many :line_items
   def paypal_url(return_url)
values = {
    :business => 'dev_1249899173_biz@gmail.com',
    :cmd => '_cart',
    :upload => 1,
    :return => return_url,
    :invoice => id
}
line_items.each_with_index do |item, index|
  values.merge!({
                    "amount_#{index+1}" => item.price,
                    "item_name_#{index+1}" => item.product.title,
                    "item_number_#{index+1}" => item.id
                    #"quantity_#{index+1}" => item.quantity
                })
end
"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
```

end

but i go to the cart page i got the following error

```
 undefined method `price' for line_items
```

i guess this error is because of block in paypal method in cart model

```
    line_items.each_with_index do |item, index|
    values.merge!({
                    "amount_#{index+1}" => item.price,
                    "item_name_#{index+1}" => item.post.title,
                    "item_number_#{index+1}" => item.id
                    #"quantity_#{index+1}" => item.quantity
                })
```

Infact i don't know how this line_items is firing here, from where those values is coming from.

Please help me to understand and fix this error. I am new to rails.

Answer (score 0):

not sure how you defined your line_item (product) but I think you should call `cart.product.price` model,and I think where you call the `full_price` on `cart`,if `cart` its al `line_item` should not keep the total price of the cart, you should get that through `@cart.full_price`.

Comment: Thanks @accelburst.do you have any idea about line_items here in the block.i can't underdtand how its firing.

Comment: anytime :), if you think the answer was right, would be nice if you mark it like it ;).

Comment: well its used to build the paypal url, the api of paypal use a get method, so the values on the url you use to access the payment is what the payment invoice shows, and uses the index to recognize every product, usually you dont need to mess to much with it, you can check the paypal documentation too to see what every parameter on the url means :).